# Disable Multi Option Select (Custom) CRM 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I found a solution that is called AmbekNet.Multiselect option, here is the solution:
[Solution gitHub](https://github.com/ambek/XRM.Multiselect)

In my CRM(8.2 v1612) i want to block all the fields depending on the selection of another  field.

I used javascript for disable all the form, but the multioptionselect is enabled evenly.

The solution of AmbekNet is generating buttons of boolean fields and i try to obtain the webResource and the element button and block it, but it doesn't work.

This is my code of javascript for disable all fields:

```
function setFieldDisabled() {
var optionset = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abs_tipodecuenta").getValue();
if (optionset == null)
{
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abs_tipodecuenta").setValue(100000000);
    Xrm.Page.getControl("abs_tipodecuenta").setDisabled(true);
}
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abs_tipodecuenta").getText() == 'Clientes' ||
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abs_tipodecuenta").getText() == 'Agencias' ||
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abs_tipodecuenta").getText() ==                                                 
        'Distribuidores') 
    {
           disableFormFields();
    } 
    else {
          enableFormFields();
          Xrm.Page.getControl("abs_tipodecuenta").setDisabled(true);
    }
}

function disableFormFields()
{
   Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, index) {
       var controlType = control.getControlType();
       if (controlType != 'iframe' && controlType != 'webresource' && 
       controlType != 'subgrid')
       {
           control.setDisabled(true);
       }
   });
}


function enableFormFields()
{
   Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control, index) {
       var controlType = control.getControlType();
       if (controlType != 'iframe' && controlType != 'webresource' && 
       controlType != 'subgrid')
       {
           control.setDisabled(false);
       }
   });
}
```

And this is the iframe i want to block:
[MultiSelect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXFMj.png)

Someone knows how to block it?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

In the abr_multiselect.js file i add this line in the method  javascript:

```
function setValue(controlName, value) {
try {
    var attr = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute(controlName);

    if (window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("abs_tipodecuenta").getValue() 
    == 100000000)
    {
    alert(value + "guardando");
        attr.setValue(value);
        attr.setSubmitMode("always");
    }

}
catch (e) {
    if ( window.console && window.console.log )
    console.log("Error: setValue", controlName, e.message);
    }
};
```

Set the value and save only if the field in my case the value is 100000000.